# .NET PowerBIClient NuGet Package adds wrong relative URI

Tags: c#, powerbi, nuget-package, power-bi-report-server

I try to encapsule our PowerBI Server REST API via the PowerBI Client NuGet Package from Microsoft.
I ran into the problem that the URI gets a wrong relative path added.
The REST API of our Reporting Server (on-premise) has a base URI like: https://niceReportingURL.com/reports/api/v2.0 but the NuGet package adds another "/v1.0/myorg" to the URI, which is not necessary.

So resulting of that, the request URI looks like this: https://niceReportingURL.com/reports/api/v2.0/v1.0/myorg

I saw in the source code of the class "ReportsOperations" that this weird relative URI gets added hardcoded!

```cs
string uriString = new Uri(new Uri(absoluteUri + (absoluteUri.EndsWith("/") ? "" : "/")), "v1.0/myorg/reports").ToString();
```

I omitted the "/Reports" in my example URIs because it looks like a general problem.
Is there an option or workaround that the NuGet Package doesn't add this relative URI?

The request looks like this:

```cs
var c = new BasicAuthenticationCredentials
        {
            UserName = "reportingUser",
            Password = "secretReportingPW"
        };

var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri("https://niceReportingURL.com/reports/api/v2.0"), c);

var result = await client.Reports.GetReportsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); // Here comes the fail
```

Comment: The PowerBI REST API and the Reporting Services API are distinct APIs with distinct endpoints. It's a little confusing because Reporting Services has been co-opted into what's now called paginated reports, but Power BI reports are not Reporting Services reports. I don't know if there's any pre-built package to access the SSRS REST APIs, but at least there's an OpenAPI [spec](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/microsoft-rs/SSRS/PBI3.0) that can be used to generate classes.

Comment: The specs make it clear that the [PBI REST API `GetReports`](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/reports/get-reports) is not the same thing as the [SSRS REST API `GetReports`](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/microsoft-rs/SSRS/PBI3.0#/Reports/GetReports) -- same terms but different endpoints with different result sets. The PBI report endpoint can be used to retrieve paginated (SSRS) reports, but not (I think) the other way around.

Comment: So the NuGet Package has not the intention to retrieve MetaData about Reports? Because I can see that under Reports I can access subscriptions of the report. And that's what I need - Reports and their metadata and subscriptions. And if I send an HTTP GET to /reports/api/v2.0/Reports/ I get the exact data I need

Comment: It retrieves metadata about Power BI reports. Not Reporting Services reports -- unless those reports are present as paginated reports in Power BI. I wish Microsoft hadn't just taken Reporting Services and rebranded it as Power BI Paginated Reports, but since they did we just have to be careful about making the distinctions ourselves. :P

Comment: What a shame. We have SSRS and PowerBI Reports and over the postman request I can see reports from the path "SSRS".

Comment: Hm thats nice stuff right there :'D Probably have to implement webservice call myself I guess

Comment: FWIW they do have [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/Reporting-Services/tree/master/APISamples) for using that API... in PowerShell and TypeScript. For C# you're probably on your own. Fortunately it's not very complicated stuff.

Comment: Yeah I will try. Thanks! Would you mind to write the TLDR as an answer please, so I can mark it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PowerBI Client package encapsulates access to the [PowerBI REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/).

This API is distinct from the [Reporting Services REST API](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/microsoft-rs/SSRS/2.0), which appears to have no ready-made NuGet package that encapsulates it, but does have an OpenAPI specification that makes it easy to use.

Both APIs have endpoints for retrieving reports, but they're different kinds of report. Confusingly, Microsoft has chosen to rebrand Reporting Services as "[paginated reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/consumer/end-user-paginated-report)" in the PowerBI ecosystem, so at least *some* Reporting Services reports can be retrieved using the PowerBI REST API. For reports hosted by an on-premise Reporting Services instance, though, you want the Reporting Services API and can't use the PowerBI REST API.